# How to close ng-bootstrap modal after login?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

**This is my button to open login modal.**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <button  class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" (click)="openLoginDialog(content)">Login</button>
</form>
```

**This is my component.ts**

```
modalReference = null;
 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }
 openLoginDialog(content) {
this.modalReference= this.modalService.open(content, { centered: true });


 }}
```

**login.component.ts**
*this is my login component where i have login function for template,i hve to close my temmplate after click on login button.My login functionallty is working fine. *

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
modalReference: any; 
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
onSubmitLogin(){   
this.dataservice.searchUser(this.user.email,this.user.password)
.subscribe(
   results =>
  { 
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('userpassword',JSON.stringify(this.user.password));
    localStorage.setItem('useremail',JSON.stringify(this.user.email));
    if(results.length == 1)
    {
      this.userlist = results;
     let id =results[0].id;
     this.dataservice.changeUser(this.userlist[0].firstName);
     this.modalReference.close();
    // this.modalService.open().close(results);
    }

    else{          
        alert ("Username Not found");
      }
  });
}}
```

**Error**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber._next (login.component.ts:78)
at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:195)
at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:133)
at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:79)
at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:1543)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3662)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:496)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)
```

Comment: All examples in the documentation show how to close the modal: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples. Read them, read the documentation, and try something.

Comment: Thanks, but trying to implement programmatically and all examples are mention by using close button separately.

Comment: Again, read the documentation. NgbModal.open() returns an NgbModalRef. And NgbModalRef is documented. It has two methods: close() and dismiss(). The component example also shows how you can inject the NgbActiveModal if you use a component as the modal body.